# Stacking labels and adding separations in matplotlib axis

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to make my x axis look like this:

[image]

so there is a "sub-title" for a group of ticks, and a separations that I can add. Is it possible doing it in matplotlib? if not, is there another tool?

*The example was taken from Wu, Lisa, et al. "Q100: The architecture and design of a database processing unit." ACM SIGPLAN Notices 49.4 (2014): 255-268.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks daryl for your comment! I've tried your solution but it seemed a bit too complex. Also, I don't necessarily want to draw the lines symmetrically.

Anyhow, I thought of another way... I hid all the ticks and added additional ticks with large length. I positioned the new ticks between the regular ticks so I got the lines I wanted.

For the labels I've used *xlabel* aligned to the right and just used spaces to align the labels in the desired position. Not the best solution here, but it worked.

It looks something like this:

```
# Modify the ticks parameters
plt.tick_params('x', bottom='on', length=80, width=1, which='major', direction='out')

# Hide all ticks
xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
for tick in xticks:
    tick.tick1On = False

# Calculate additional tick marks positions
t_list = list(ax.get_xticks())
t1 = (t_list[5] + t_list[4])/2
t2 = (t_list[7] + t_list[6])/2
t3 = (t_list[13] + t_list[12])/2

# Add ticks
ax.set_xticks(list(ax.get_xticks()) + [t1, t2, t3])

# Make the ticks visible
xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
xticks[15].tick1On = True
xticks[16].tick1On = True
xticks[17].tick1On = True

# Position the labels
plt.xlabel('L1   L2   ', fontsize=14, labelpad=10, horizontalalignment='right', x=1.0)
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab at this, the trick is to create a transparent overlay axis that I can use to draw the vertical bars near the xaxis and the 3 cat labels. Hopefully somebody more clever than I comes up with a something more elegant!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import lines

labels = ['LowPower Design', 'Pareto Design', 'HighPerf Design']
cats = ['q14', 'q19', 'q8', 'q6', 'q17', 'q7', 'q5', 'q15', 'q4', 'q1', 'q3',
    'q16', 'q18', 'q21', 'q2', 'q20', 'q10', 'q11']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7])
ax.set_xlim(0.5, len(cats) * 3 + 0.5)
ax.set_xticks(range(1, len(cats) * 3 + 1))
ax.set_xticklabels(cats * 3, rotation=90)

# new transparent axis
ax2 = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0))

pos = ax.get_position()
deltax = pos.width / 3.
for i in range(4):
    xpos = pos.x0 + deltax * i
    line = lines.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [0.2, 0.05], lw=2., color='k')
    ax2.add_line(line)

    if i < 3:
        ax2.text(xpos + deltax / 2., 0.05, labels[i], ha='center')

fig.savefig('test.png')
```

[image: example image]